# I have a blender model I'm trying to import but I can't see it

Tags: three.js

```
class _the_thinkrium_scene {

 // private

    constructor()  {
    
    THREE.Scene.prototype.thinkrium_scene = this;

    THREE.Scene.prototype.thinkrium_scene.scene = new THREE.Scene();    
    
    THREE.Scene.prototype.thinkrium_scene.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    
    THREE.Scene.prototype.thinkrium_scene.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    
    THREE.Scene.prototype.thinkrium_scene.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    
    THREE.Scene.prototype.thinkrium_scene.renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
    
    THREE.Scene.prototype.thinkrium_scene.loading_manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
    
    THREE.Scene.prototype.thinkrium_scene.loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
    
    
    THREE.Scene.prototype.thinkrium_scene.renderer.setClearColor(0xccccee);
    
    THREE.Scene.prototype.thinkrium_scene.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    
    THREE.Scene.prototype.thinkrium_scene.add_lights();
    
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
    
    THREE.Scene.prototype.thinkrium_scene.scene.add(this.camera);
    
    THREE.Scene.prototype.thinkrium_scene.camera.position.set( 0, 2, 3 );
    
    THREE.Scene.prototype.thinkrium_scene.camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
    
    THREE.Scene.prototype.thinkrium_scene.load("themes/TheThinkrium/js/front_page/peterweb.dae");
}

// add_lights
// params: none
// functions: adds the lights to the scene
// returns: none
add_lights() {

    THREE.Scene.prototype.thinkrium_scene.ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
    THREE.Scene.prototype.thinkrium_scene.scene.add(
        THREE.Scene.prototype.thinkrium_scene.ambientLight
    );

}

// loader_setup
// params: object - three js scene context
// functions: loads the model from blender
// returns: none
loader_setup(context) {

 
    var animations = context.animations;
    var avatar = context.scene;
    

    
    avatar.traverse( function ( node ) {
        if ( node.isSkinnedMesh ) {
            node.frustumCulled = false;
        }
    } );
    
    var mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( avatar );
    
    mixer.clipAction( animations[ 0 ] ).play();

    console.log(THREE.Scene.prototype.thinkrium_scene);
    THREE.Scene.prototype.thinkrium_scene.scene.add(avatar);

}

// loader_pretext
// params: xhr - the loading info
// functions : uses the xhr to describe how much information is left to load
// returns: none
loader_pretext(xhr) {
    console.log(Math.floor((xhr.loaded / xhr.totalSize) * 100));
    
}

// loading_errors
// params: error - error context
// functions : logs errors to  debug
// returns : none
loading_errors(err) {
    console.log(err);
}

// load
// params: name - the name of the model
// functions: loads the model 
// returns: none
load(name) {

    THREE.Scene.prototype.thinkrium_scene.loader.load(
        name, 
        THREE.Scene.prototype.thinkrium_scene.loader_setup, 
        THREE.Scene.prototype.thinkrium_scene.loader_pretext, 
        THREE.Scene.prototype.thinkrium_scene.loading_errors
    );
}


// get_renderer
// params: none
// functions : gets the renderer
// returns: renderer 
get_renderer() {
    return THREE.Scene.prototype.thinkrium_scene.renderer;    
}

// get_renderer
// params: none
// functions : gets the renderer
// returns: renderer 
get_scene() {
    return THREE.Scene.prototype.thinkrium_scene.scene;    
}

// get_renderer
// params: none
// functions : gets the renderer
// returns: renderer 
get_camera() {
    return THREE.Scene.prototype.thinkrium_scene.camera;    
}

}
```

Another file:

```
"using strict"
/*
 *
 *   standards : 
 *
 *     params are in the form of camelCase 
 *     local vars are in the form of '_' i.e. these_are_vars
 *
 *     class definitions are in the form of "_name"
 *     class declarations are in the form of "name"
 *
 *     public and private vars are defined
 *    
 *
 *   notations :
 *     
 *     function_name {}
 *     params : value - definition
 *     params : value - definition
 *     functions : definition
 *     returns : value - definition
 *
 *
 *
 */

 // main {}
 // params : none
 // functions : operates as the main entry point for the thinkrium scene
 // returns : nothing
 function main() {

     var scene = new _the_thinkrium_scene();
     animate( scene.get_renderer(),  scene.get_scene(),  scene.get_camera() );
     window.onresize = resize(scene.get_renderer());


}

// animate
// params: none
// functions: sets up the request animation frame
// returns: none
function animate( theRenderer, theScene, theCamera) {

    window.requestAnimationFrame(function(theRenderer, theScene, theCamera) {

    
    });
    theRenderer.render( theScene, theCamera );

};

// resize
// params: none
// functions: resizes the screen
// return: none
function resize(_renderer) {
    _renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}


window.onload = main();
```

I can't get my model in the scene, I think it's because I lose context.

But when I console.log the prototyped this than it's all in there.

Originally I had the THREE.Scene.prototype.thinkrium_scene  as just a this object, but when I get into my callbacks I lose scope.

I prototype the `this` object into the `THREE.Scene` but it doesn't seem to matter. I can't seem to bind a context to any context to get the this object out of the loader callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's some hard to read code. You must really like typing. What is up with all those lines;

```
THREE.Scene.prototype.thinkrium_scene.
```

It looks like you're initializing a renderer for each scene? There should only be one.

The rest of the code seems OK (as far as i can see through the jungle of letters), i suspect no error messages? 
Maybe the model you are exporting is very small, or even really big? Try setting the scale.

What happens if you just add a three.mesh with a cubeGeometry? Is that visible?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize it but the reason it was not running is I wasn't calling my rAF correctly.... I appreciate it